# Is Null causing access table to go over 2GB and fail

Tags: sql-server, ms-access

I am sending queries from MS Access (office 365) to MS SQL 2016 and I am running into an error where the temp table from the query I am running is causing MS Access to fail once the max size of 2GB is reached.

The odd thing is that this only happens when I query for `Is Null`.

This query has been working for a long time and only recently started failing after I updated the underlying data table with the last months working information.

If I search for a value instead of `Null` it works just fine.

Any idea on what is causing this?

I was able to to verify that the information from the most recent month is fine and I can pull all the information I loaded in a separate query without triggering the 2GB max size table issue.

```
SELECT 
    dbo_FY2018TRD.[ACCOUNT NUMBER], 
    dbo_FY2018TRD.[ACCOUNT SHORT NAME], 
    dbo_FY2018TRD.[ACCOUNT NAME], 
    dbo_FY2018TRD.[ACCOUNT RR], 
    dbo_FY2018TRD.[ACCOUNT RR NAME], 
    dbo_FY2018TRD.[ACCOUNT BKR], 
    dbo_FY2018TRD.[ACCOUNT BKR NAME]
FROM 
    dbo_FY2018TRD LEFT JOIN FullRRTable ON dbo_FY2018TRD.[ACCOUNT RR] = FullRRTable.[RRCode]
WHERE 
    (((FullRRTable.RRCode) Is Null));
```

*Explanation from comments*: The temp table being used is the generic one MS Access creates. The large table `dbo_FY2018TRD` sits in the SQL server but the `FullRRTable` sits in Access. I split them up like this because the `FullRRTable` I routinely edit to apply labels but the `dbo_FY2018TRD` table should never be modified other than to add new records. `dbo_FY2018TRD` is 27 million rows by 50 columns, whereas FullRRTable is 35,000 rows by 5 columns.

Comment: I guess the  query simply returns too much data. As an experiment you could for example try Is Null `AND` some other filter to reduce the dataset and see if that works. It seems like you may have run out scale in MS Access

Comment: Which table was just updated???   dbo_FY2018TRD  OR  FullRRTable ??  Can you run COUNT(*) on each table to see how many rows have Is Null of the RRCode?  Have the table(s) always had that number of Nulls?

Comment: Table that was updated was dbo_FY2018TRD - basically every month this table get new records and for the vast majority of the records I already have the RRCode in the the FullRRTable. The purpose of the Is Null is to find which RRCode value I am missing from the FullRRTable as a result of the new data loaded into dbo_FY2018TRD.

Comment: There is nothing special about `Is Null` in a query, so this definitely has to do with your tables and what data is being returned.  Certainly the cause must be with other processes (like the source of the monthly update) that cannot be guessed at by anyone here.  You replied to donPablo's questions, but the most important thing you could do is what was already suggested...  run something like `SELECT Count(*) FROM dbo_FY2018TRD LEFT JOIN FullRRTable ON dbo_FY2018TRD.[ACCOUNT RR] = FullRRTable.[RRCode] WHERE (FullRRTable.RRCode Is Null)` to get summary data before tackling the details.

Comment: You could try if an `NOT EXISTS` works better.

Comment: 2Gb in one table is an awful lot of data especially with only a handful of fields, assuming all other tables are linked. How many records are you trying to return? it must be squillions ? (Squillions is the new ISO standard name for shed loads)

Comment: Squillions = N ... the table is about 27M (annualized) records but the returned records are typically only 1,000 to 2,000 per month. Records loaded per month range from 2M-3M. So as I mentioned before when I search for a single string "client name A" it works with zero lag or issues. However if search from more than 1 string "client name A" or "client name B"...BOOM right off the rails again (2GB issue).

Comment: Just tried the SELECT Count(*) FROM dbo_FY2018TRD LEFT JOIN FullRRTable ON dbo_FY2018TRD.[ACCOUNT RR] = FullRRTable.[RRCode] WHERE (FullRRTable.RRCode Is Null) ...(sorry this took awhile to run) results returned 4,777 (a little higher than usual but nowhere near enough results to blow out 2GB)

Comment: What is the exact error and/or behavior?  We're all assuming this is about a 2GB data limit, but does the error say that explicitly?

Comment: Ah... the "temp" table is in Access. Perhaps I should have suspected as much given the difference in table names, but from the question text I was assuming that "sending queries... to MS SQL 2016" meant a passthrough query... all run on the server. I was also assuming from the description of a monthly process and the name **Full**RRTable that this table was the larger one. In the future 1) please include detail (size, location) table info with questions; and 2) "temp table" refers to an automatic temporary table in SQL Server, so this is not a useful term to use for describing an Access table.

Comment: @CPerkins You should submit your comments as an answer to get the credit.

Comment: @donPablo  A well-formed, focused question with adequate information deserves an actual answer.  In a case like this, where the details come slowly, and a good portion of the help is guiding someone through debugging steps, I hesitate to post a premature answer that is really just a guess.  Comments and debugging help posted as answers actually messes up the flow... how the question is handled for triage, etc.

Answer (score 1):

Comments reveal that the smaller "temp" table `FullRRTable` is in the Access database and the table `dbo_FY2018TRD` is on the SQL Server.  Because the query involves tables in both locations, the full query cannot be sent to the server as a pass-through query.

For a mixed query, Access must essentially request all rows from the Server table `dbo_FY2018TRD` since it must perform the join locally without the benefit of server indices, etc. There may be no optimization (or perhaps only one-sided using indices for the Access table), so Access will perform a row-by-row comparison for all record combinations. If you have the ability to inspect record requests from the server, you may also observe that Access requests the same row multiple times.

2 GB divided by 27 million records of the `dbo_FY2018TRD` table is around 74 bytes per row, making the limit definitely reachable.  Divide that into 7 fields of the original query and it's about 10 bytes per field--not including packaging bytes--also a reasonable estimate.

---

That answers the basic question *"Any idea on what is causing this?"*.  As for a solution, I would consider downloading **only** the single key field `dbo_FY2018TRD.[ACCOUNT RR]` that you're using in the join to a "temporary" table in Access, then run the comparison query against that table.  The results of that query could then be used to retrieve only the mismatched rows.

Search for "access linked table index" or "access linked table mixed query" for more varied suggestions, although you have to dig to find bits of useful info.

Comment: Another possibility that I have used is to upload the smaller table from Access to a @temptable in sqlserver, and then allow the join to be performed there.  It is only one column, and its rowcount is lower that the sql table.